# Unable to install pywinrm without upgrading and breaking pip

Tags: python, module, pip, winrm

When trying to install the module via pip, it says I need to install setuptools 18.5 or higher. So I do a "pip install -U pip" it upgrades my pip version to 10.0.1. Then when I try to install the pywinrm module, it breaks with a Syntax Error.
In fact, it breaks all Pip commands when upgrading to 10.0.1.  I have it currently installed with version 7.1.0 and Python 2.6.6

I try this:

pip install pywinrm

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
   from pip._internal import main
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
   from pip._internal import cmdoptions
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
   from pip._internal.index import (
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 526
   {str(c.version) for c in all_candidates},
                     ^â
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Ehm, why Python 2.6 if I may ask? https://snarky.ca/stop-using-python-2-6/

Comment: Another thing, you should upgrade `setuptools` in the first place and not `pip`. `pip install --user "setuptools<37"` should do the trick: 1. most probably `setuptools` is managed by the system's package manager, so install a second version as user and 2. `setuptools` [dropped Python 2.6 support since version 37](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v37-0-0).